# My subdomain on Wordpress Multisite has gone

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I have a WordPress multisite; the main site is, for example,  `www.example.com` and 
the subdomain is `tv.example.com`.

I have had my main site for close to 2 years and created the multisite in November to enable me to have a subdomain.

Today I went online and my subdomain is offline. I am also unable to access the admin area for this subdomain.

I don't understand what could have gone wrong and the last time I made any edits on the site was 3 weeks ago and it has been working fine since then till this point.

How can I restore my subdomain?

error message:

```
404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:
tv.example.com/wp-admin/ (port 80)
Please forward this error screen to tv.example.com's WebMaster.
```

Apache Server at `tv.example.com` Port 80

Comment: Have you contacted your hosting provider?

Comment: Hi max,  I left an answer as thw comments have characters restrictions and I had a lot to say.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. I contacted my host, they said WordPress multi-site has nothing to do with them, and doesn't show up on my host subdomain area, so they couldn't help.

I was able to get the site back. I got my host to restore my backup file from 2weeks ago. Everything was back to normal,  I lost a few articles but I have draft somewhere.

The problem I faced definitely has to do with theme support. I created a  subdomain with my host, about.example.com and bought a html theme, gave my cpanel login to theme support to install. Something they did most have had a negative reaction to my WordPress multi-site.

I found WordPress multi-site great because I could easily navigate from one to the other, however it has its cons. The fact that I couldn't get any immediate support from WordPress apart from the forum worried me. I am now exporting/recreating the subdomain I had on WordPress multi-site with my host (for support reasons). Also another problem I experienced were the plugin clashes, plugins from a theme used on one site clashed with the plugins from the other site; I did figured a way around this.  But my website going offline prompted me to keep each separate and avoid future complicationd.

Both websites have the same menue so it's easy for my users to move between both sites; so subdomain with my host will have to do. Not going to fine it fun to log in and out of each  site to update.

Hope the above experience will help someone else.

Thank you again max for responding,  I don't always get a responds so I appreciate.

Comment: "theme support" are the keywords. WordPress itself can't alter the settings without external actions. Unless explicitly specified otherwise in a theme or a plugin.